# How can I calculate the root of any order of power series

Tags: equation-solving, programming, fitting, series-expansion

How can I calculate the root of any order of power series with *Mathematica*.

Here I insert every quantity by hand. But I want to give `a`, `b`, `n`, `L` values and order of series and so automatically calculate all `r` and ECornell values.

```
n = 0; a = 1; L = 0; b = 0.01; m = 1/2 ; g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);
f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3)  (r)];
NumberForm[FindMaximum[r^(L + 1) f[r], {r}], {13, 13}];
r0 = 4.103398736759;

Series[1/r, {r, r0, 4}]
r1inv = 0.24370042107821896 -0.05938989523370123 (r1 - 4.103398736759) +0.0144733424762443 (r1 - 4.103398736759)^2 - 0.0035271596558700082 (r1 - 4.103398736759)^3 + 0.0008595702933456269 (r1 - 4.103398736759)^4;
NumberForm[Solve[r1inv - 1/r == 0, r], {13, 13}];
NumberForm[FindRoot[r1inv - 1/r == 0, {r, 13}], {13, 13}];
NumberForm[r1 = 1/r1inv, {13, 13}];
NumberForm[ECornell = -((m a^2)/(2 (n + L + 1)^2)) + (a/(L + 1) - (L + 1)/(m r1)) f'[r1]/f[r1], {13, 13}];
```

Comment: Do you mean, `Solve[0 == Normal@Series[1/r, {r, r0, 4}], r]`?

Comment: no. I mean,  1/r=Series[1/r, {r, r0, 4}]

Comment: So, adapt my code snippet to yours? Maybe I don't know what you mean by "root of any order of power series". Can you edit your post with more details?

Comment: ok. I see :) thank you. I will try it

Comment: in fact my problem is above. here I insert every quantity by hand.  tried to your suggestion but not work

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 0;
a = 1;
L = 0;
b = 1/100;
m = 1/2;
g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);
f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3) r];

r0 = r /.
    FindMaximum[r^(L + 1) f[r], r, WorkingPrecision -> 20][[2]] //
     Rationalize[#, 0] &;

r0 // N // InputForm

(*  4.103398736759  *)

r1inv = Series[1/r, {r, r0, 4}] //
    Normal // Simplify;

r0 == r /. Solve[r1inv - 1/r == 0, r, Reals][[1]]

(*  True  *)

r0 == r /. FindRoot[r1inv - 1/r == 0, {r, r0}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 16]

(*  True  *)

Clear[ECornell]

ECornell[r_] = -((m a^2)/(2 (n + L + 1)^2)) +
    (a/(L + 1) - (L + 1)/(m r)) f'[r]/f[r] //
   Simplify;

(ECornell[1/r1inv] /. r -> r0) == ECornell[r0]

(*  True  *)

Plot[{ECornell[r], ECornell[1/r1inv]},
 {r, 0, 8},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {
   Tooltip[Text["r0", {r0, 0}, {0, -1.5}], r0 // N],
   Red, Dashed,
   Line[{{r0, 0}, {r0, ECornell[r0]}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: My aim is to fit the r0(rmax) to the r1. 
For b=0.01 ad L=0 r0(r_max)=4.103398736759 but I must fit the r1=1.7436481088. 
This is why?
Because, if and only if I'm using this value(r1=1.7436481088) can go to the correct result for ECornell=-0.2210305634048.

Comment: The match will be at the expansion point. You chose `r0` as the expansion point so the match is there.

Comment: Can you give more details? I don't know what you mean

Comment: Truncated series expansions are only good approximations near the expansion point. The fewer terms used the closer you need to be to the expansion point. Note that the curves diverge as you move away from the expansion point (`r0`). If you know that you want a close fit at some particular `r` value then use that `r` value as the expansion point.

Comment: you are right. thanks